# c - SIGSEGV reported using pow()

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

Compiler threw a SIGSEGV at `tmp = pow(p[i],j);` while `p[i]` and `j` are two integers, and `p[i]` is a valid element of array `p`, I really don't know why...

Original code is here:http://pastebin.com/DYhGeHxm

Comment: add assert statements before every point where you call `p[i]` along the lines of `assert(i < 2000);` -- this should allow you to catch where you're exceeding the end of the array (which is almost certainly where the Seg Fault is coming from). In general, it's always best practise to loop over the array index directly, rather than other numbers you think are correlated.

Comment: Also, the `while` loop @ line 56 - it's an infinite loop. Did You forget a `break` statement?

Comment: @tehwalrus value of i isn't getting larger than 2000

Comment: @Vinska I just debugged lines not after 47

Comment: I didn't mean to imply only `p` - wherever you use `pointer_variable[i]` you should always know that `i` will be less than the length, either because you're in a loop that explicitly only goes that far, or because you `assert()`. it's the safest way, and it shows you what line the errors occur on (unlike a segfault). you can remove the asserts (preferably with a preprocessor flag, so you can reenable them) for production if you care about performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Has it occurred to you that this:

```
int i,j,p[2000], a[5000000],num,count,tmp;
```

may be pushing you either very near, or outright *over* the brink of your stack space? That is

```
4 + 4 + 8000 + 20000000 + 4 + 4 + 4
```

**bytes**

I.e. you have a **19.08 megabyte** stack space declaration. Consider dynamically allocating `a` at least. When i changed it to be:

```
int *a = malloc(5000000 * sizeof(*a));
```

and reran the code, it made it well past the seg-fault you have. unfortunately, it died at this location:

```
count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for(j = 2; ;j++) {
        tmp = pow(p[i],j);
        if(tmp > 5000000) break;
        a[count++] = tmp; // <=== faulted here, count was 5000193
    }
}
```

Both loops should break when you reach the allocated max size of `a[]`. I did the following. At the top of `main()`:

```
static const int a_max = 5000000;
int *a = malloc(a_max*sizeof(*a));
```

Down in the loop:

```
count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < num && count < a_max; i++)
{
    for(j = 2; count < a_max; j++)
    {
        tmp = pow(p[i],j);
        if(tmp > 5000000)
            break;
        a[count++] = tmp;
    }
}
```

This gets you past all the setup. The last thing is the quicksort algorithm itself, which appears broken as well. I *highly* advise starting with smaller data sizes to debug that.

Best of luck.

---

**EDIT** In case you needed a reference quicksort algorithm, i had one sitting in a source file in one of my junk folders. No guarantees its even right (pretty sure it is, and skips length-1 sorts too), but I know it doesn't hang, so it has that going for it =P

```
// quicksort for ints
static void quicksort_ints(int *arr, int left, int right)
{
    int p = (left+right)/2;    // as good as any
    int l = left, r = right;   // movable indicies

    while (l <= r)
    {
        while (arr[l] < arr[p])
            ++l;
        while (arr[r] > arr[p])
            --r;
        if (l <= r)
        {
            int tmp = arr[l];
            arr[l] = arr[r];
            arr[r] = tmp;
            ++l;
            --r;
        }
    }

    if (left < r)
        quicksort_ints(arr, left, r);
    if (l < right)
        quicksort_ints(arr, l, right);
}
```

Comment: @CDT that is not the solution. There are several *logic* errors in your code as-written. Changing the size of `a[]` on the stack with *nowhere* in your code actually using that element count based on `a[]`s declaration (`sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`) in nuts. You have code in here (some of it wrong) that expects it to be 5-million elements wide. Changing it to 500 and just hitting the run button isn't going to get you anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I mean I don't think the OP's problem is stack space, but you are def. correct.

Comment: @TheKingDave it was *easily* the initial problem. There are plenty of others in the code, but this gets past that one. I already pointed out one. Look at the test for `tmp > 5000000` to break that loop. How does that protected `count++` from overrunning the array? As I said, there are other issues, but this was the showstopper from the get-go.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you so much ! It seems malloc should be used on giant arrays... I'll mark this.

Comment: @CDT ok. there you go. follow that and i should stand a good chance of getting you to your quicksort run (which is hanging, btw, so there is a boundary miscalculation somewhere in there). Sorry I don't have time to debug that. best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `i`. Might be too large for the `p` array. You can do this with the debugger.

Comment: Agreed I also think this is a homework exercise ... Not sure of the rules.

Comment: What are the values of `p[i]` and `j`] that you discovered using the debugger?